# second printf not working when using a variable C-programming

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int a;
    printf("enter your number\n");
    scanf("%d\n", a);
    printf("your number is %d\n", a);
}
```

So basically here's the code and i don't know where's my mistake ?
after i enter the number . the program stops working

Comment: `scanf("%d\n", &a) ;`

Comment: Remove the `\n` from the `scanf` format string and pass `&a` as the argument.

Comment: whats the "&" for ? i just started to learn C so i don't know basics very well

Comment: What's with the salty comments?  & gets a pointer to the int.  It passes the memory location of the local variable called 'a'.  If you read the '%d' details for scanf, you see it requires an 'int*' which you get with &a.

Comment: @melpomene Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the pointer of a to scanf and remove \n from scanf. 
If you want to go on a new line add \n before your number is...

The code becomes like that

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int a;
    printf("enter your number\n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("\nyour number is %d\n", a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `scanf` receives a pointer to the variable you want to populate - it's address in memory. (You can scan more than one at once).
To get the address of a variable in C, use the `&` operator before it's name.

```
scanf("%d", &a); // Why do you need the \n?
```